# Validation in a simple DDD example

Tags: design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design

I'm doing a simple project that represents a CI Pipeline in a low scale. So I'm trying to model "the best way possible" to practice DDD.

Basically I have the following information:

- `PipelineSettings` (A configuration file that shows me the steps the pipeline will have)
- `PipelineSteps` (A collection of classes implementing an interface that will execute part of the job)

I started with a class called `RunPipeline` that work as a command/application service.

`RunPipeline` has two repositories `IPipelineSettingsRepository` & `IPipelineStepsRepository` and I was thinking in creating a `Pipeline` object that will be a domain object inside this command.

So the code would be something like this:

```
public class RunPipeline {

    private readonly IPipelineSettingsRepository pipelineSettingsRepository;
    private readonly IPipelineJobsRepository pipelineJobsRepository;

    public RunPipeline(
        IPipelineSettingsRepository pipelineSettingsRepository,
        IPipelineJobsRepository pipelineJobsRepository) {

        this.pipelineSettingsRepository = pipelineSettingsRepository;
        this.pipelineJobsRepository = pipelineJobsRepository;
    }

    public async Task Run(BuildOrder buildOrder) {
        var pipelineSettings = pipelineSettingsRepository.GetAll();
        var pipelineSteps = pipelineJobsRepository.GetAll();
        var pipeline = new Pipeline(pipelineSettings, pipelineSteps);

        await pipeline.Run(buildOrder);
    }

}
```

But I need to perform a validation that is that every pipeline setting is backed by a pipeline step, because if not I will try to execute a step that will not be able to be executed and it will fail.

So I was thinking in a few options:

- Have a Pipeline factory that has a validation service injected, verifies and then returns the Pipeline object
- Have a domain service that creates a `Steps` object containing inside a collection of Steps containing a **PipelineSetting**(config) for that Step and a **PipelineStep**(execution) and inject that to the `Pipeline` object.
- To inject or create internally a validator in the `Pipeline` object.
- To validate this in the RunPipeline command *(I don't think this would be good cause I could create a pipeline with an incorrect state)*
- To create a **Validate** method in Pipeline object and pass a `IPipelineValidation` implementation and pass it from RunPipeline command.

I'm thinking that Pipeline is the core of the app, and should execute concrete behaviours since is what it's solving a specific problem for this business.

What do you think?

Comment: It's worth noting that DDD is a *design* technique, not a *coding* technique.  If you want to do it "correctly," my observation is that you appear to be working backwards from the code into the business domain, instead of establishing a business domain and ubiquitous language and seeing what code naturally arises from that.  The book "Learning Domain-Driven Design" by Vlad Khononov doesn't even talk about code until page 63.

Comment: I started by trying to find the relevant words when talking and searching for CI pipelines. Understanding that a Pipeline run Steps and handle and make choices based on a configuration.
I was just having the doubt of injecting to the pipeline a service to validate that what I want to run is valid, so everytime I create a pipeline its in a valid state, or if I should do it in a PipelineFactory.
Again, the example is very simple, but just wanted to try to design it correctly

Comment: Alright.  Doesn't seem to have much to do with DDD, though.

Comment: Curiously, pipelines are just the opposite of DDD. While DDD put emphasis on conciliating data structures and behavior, Pipelines are pure behavior decoupled from the data they manage

Answer (score 0):

> [..] Pipeline is the core of the app, and should execute concrete behaviours [..]

In object-orientation *every* object is supposed to execute behavior. Combined with DDD, that behavior should be specifically business-related behavior.

In this context, I think there are too many abstractions here, some only tangentially relevant to the domain. Specifically I think `PipelineSettings` is a technical thing. What behavior does it have in your model? `PipelineStep` is good, although sounds a bit technical, I would perhaps call it `Task` (as some CI systems do). I suspect `Pipeline` could be a `Task`, if it has the same exposed behavior (i.e. run it).

The `RunPipeline` sounds and looks like a procedure. It gets data from somewhere and does something with someone else's data. This should belong to a proper object.

Overall I suspect (and I don't know your specifics of course) this could be achieved with less number of abstractions (i.e. simpler), and less procedurally (i.e. more maintainably).

Comment: First thanks for the answer :)

* I agree it is not a complicated domain and could be simpler, but I just wanted to see if this type of small project can help me to solve some doubts.

* I agree PipelineStep could be call Task or Job (like CI systems have Pipeline->Stages>Jobs)

Pipeline is the one that will iterate each step and will use pipelineStepSettings to determinate what to do in case something happens. (ex: if the step can fail it will continue, if not will throw an error)
Also will be in charge of filling a file to show the state of the pipeline